# what 's the difference between the core dump generate by different linux version?

Tags: linux, gcc, coredump, suse

I have two PCs,
the first one has gcc 4.3.2 and Linux Suse 11.0. It generates a core dump, but it has no source code of my program.
The second has gcc 4.1 and linux suse 10.1 and has the source code of my program.

Could I use the core dump generated by the first one to debug on the second PC?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a copy of the symbols then yes you could, but you'd need to get the symbols to do this.

Have a peek at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329986/remote-post-mortem-coredump-analysis-without-having-exact-debug-symbols-for-shar)