# Relevant debug data for a Linux target

Tags: linux, debugging, arm, report

For an embedded ARM system running in-field there is a need to retrieve relevant debug information when a user-space application crash occurs. Such information will be stored in a non-volatile memory so it could be retreived at a later time. All such information must be stored during runtime, and cannot use third-party applications due to memory consumption concerns.

So far I have thought of following:

1. **Signal ID** and corresponding  **PC / memory addresses** in case a kernel SIG occurs;
2. Process ID;

What other information do you think it's relevant in order to indentify the causing problem and be able to do a fast debug afterwards?

Thank you!

Comment: If you weren't aware, it might help to know some ARM SoCs have an [Embedded Trace Buffer](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.set.coresight/index.html#tracebuffers) to do exactly this sort of thing in hardware.

Comment: @Notlikethat Thank you for your helpfull information. Indeed, I was not aware of the mentioned Trace HW functionality. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, to be able to understand an issue, you'll need every register (from r0 to r15), the CPSR, and the top of the stack (to be able to determine what happened before the crash). Please also note that, when your program is interrupt for any invalid operation (jump to invalid address, ...), the processor goes to an exception mode, while you need to dump the registers and stack in the context of your process.

To be able to investigate, using those data, you also must keep the ELF files (with debug information, if possible) from your build, to be able to interpret the content of your registers and stack.

In the end, the more information you keep, the easier the debug is, but it may be expensive to keep every memory sections used by your program at the time of the failure (as a matter of fact, I've never done this).

In postmortem analysis, you will face some limits :

- Dynamically linked libraries : if your crash occurs in a dynamically loaded and linked code, [you will also need the lib binary you are using on your target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329986/remote-post-mortem-coredump-analysis-without-having-exact-debug-symbols-for-shar).
- Memory corruption : memory corruption usually results in the call of random data as code. On ARM with linux, this will probably lead to a segfault, as you can't go to an other process memory area, and as your data will probably be marked as "never execute", nevertheless, when the crash happens, you may have already corrupted the data that could have allow you to identify the source of the corruption. Postmortem analysis isn't always able to identify the failure cause.